# Angular - Is it possible to load a jquery plugin for one component?

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins

I've tried to do everything in angular and not use jQuery. Unfortunately, there's one component that requires it. However, I would like to only load the jQuery plugin .js file on that component (so it's not being loaded everywhere...)

**I have done the following**

1. npm install jquery --save
2. npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
3. Update Angular-cli.json > scripts > jQuery.min.js

**Questions**

1. Is it worth just loading the plugin in the index file?
2. If not, how is it possible to load the plugin file on the one component that's going to use it?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've loaded the jQuery plugin as mentioned in the answer, but there's an error on:

'$("#myCanvas").annotate(options);'

> [ts] Property 'annotate' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

Is there a disconnect between the loaded file and the typescript file?

```js
  loadAnnotate(): void {
    const jQueryCdnUrl = `assets/scripts/djaodjin-annotate.js`;
    const node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = jQueryCdnUrl;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = false;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
  }


  loadAnnotateSettings(){
    var counter = 0;

   $('#myCanvas').on("annotate-image-added", function(event, id, path){
    $(".my-image-selector").append("<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"image-selector\" class=\"annotate-image-select\" value=\"" + path + "\" checked id=\"" + id + "\"><img src=\"" + path + "\" width=\"35\" height=\"35\"></label>");
   });


   var options = {
    width: "600",   // Width of canvas
    height: "400",   // Height of canvas
    color:"red",    // Color for shape and text
    type : "rectangle",  // default shape: can be "rectangle", "arrow" or "text"
    images: ['https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg'],   // Array of images path : ["images/image1.png", "images/image2.png"]
    linewidth:2,   // Line width for rectangle and arrow shapes
    fontsize:"20px",  // font size for text
    bootstrap: true,  // Bootstrap theme design
    position: "top",  // Position of toolbar (available only with bootstrap)
    idAttribute: "id",  // Attribute to select image id.
    selectEvent: "change", // listened event to select image
    unselectTool: false  // display an unselect tool for mobile
      }
      
      

      $("#myCanvas").annotate(options);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor() {
  this.loadJQuery()

  const script = document.getElementById('dynamicScript')
  script.onload = //Do your thing now

}


loadJquery(): void {
  const jQueryCdnUrl = `jquerycdn`;
  const node = document.createElement('script');
  node.src = jQueryCdnUrl;
  node.type = 'text/javascript';
  node.async = false;
  node.id = 'dynamicScript'
  node.charset = 'utf-8';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Manzur. Apologies, this is a bit vague for me. Where would this go exactly? Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: `text/javascript` is the default type of script tags if you're using HTML5, so you should be able to omit that.

Comment: @ETX This would replace your implementation of including jQuery in the Angular CLI global and move it to the component.

Comment: Updated the answer, you just need to call this function in your constructor or on ngOnInit

Comment: Thanks all. In my question I mention that I already have jquery installed. I have another plugin jquery file. This is the file that I wasn't sure where to load. I'm assuming I can use the same approach in your answer for 'myPlugin.js' file too?

Comment: Yea, sorry for overlooking, it can be used for any script file, enjoy!

Comment: Thanks again. Very much appreciate the time. I tried to implement this and received an error. Original post updated. When loading a jquery plugin file in the way outlined in your answer, is it not possible to use syntax from that file (in this instance 'annotate') in the ts file?

Comment: I guess, it might be because your script is not loaded when it's being use, I have updated it again, you can try that, hope it works

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Hopefully this is the last question :) - 'document.getElementById('dynamicScript')' - What is this supposed to reference?

Comment: So first in the loadJquery function we are inserting an script element inside the dom, in order to know whether the script was loaded, while creating the element we are assigning it an Id for reference. 
After inserting the element, we are getting our newly inserted element in the constructor function and checking if it's loaded.
So  document.getElementById('dynamicScript')' is supposed to reference our newly created element

Comment: I think I might have to give in on this one. I changed: const script = document.getElementById('annotator'). I added the id in the loadjQuery code: node.id = "annotator"; In the 'script.onload' I changed it to 'script.onload = function() { this loadAnnotateSettings}'. I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165047/discussion-between-etx-and-manzur-khan-sarguroh).

Comment: @ETX Also see: https://netbasal.com/using-typescript-dynamic-imports-in-angular-d210547484dd