# How to import external javascript file in angulars5 component html file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, web-deployment

I have one component folder, is map (which is create for Google map).

This map folder contains *`map.component.html`, `map.component.css`, `map.component.ts`* files.

I have also external javascript file `route.js` which is use for loading map on map.

`component.html` file (which is in map component folder). So how am I import `route.js` file to `map.component.html`. How am I load `google.maps.Map()` instance onto `map.component.html`. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load external javascript file from Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204417/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-from-angular-component)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 referencing external js file in index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376263/angular-2-referencing-external-js-file-in-index-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Is it possible to load a jquery plugin for one component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765295/angular-is-it-possible-to-load-a-jquery-plugin-for-one-component)